# Do I need to validate userpreferences login and password every time user opens my app?

Tags: android, android-studio

when user first login I save it like this:

```
                            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref01", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                            editor.putString("username", username);
                            editor.putString("password", password);
                            editor.apply();
```

next time he opens the app I get this username value in loginactivity automatically and, automatically, open user area if username is set by shared preferences.

So everytime the user upload an image, do some changes on his account I give this username stored in userpreferences to PHP.

My question is, is it ok? or do I need to check user and password everytime user opens my app? can user change the sharedpreferences? because, for example, if user 'maria' changes it to 'josh' she will login automatically in josh account... is it possible to happen?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of saving login detail use token. When user login then in response of api call send token generated from server itself & Save it to preference. Use this token in every other api as Auth key. So user also can't change it and even if token is changed then server will know that token is inviladate as your token generation logic then logout user from app redirect UI to login screen.